# ASIO4ALL : How do I use it in my C project?

Tags: c, audio, driver, pcm, asio

I'm building a very basic, console-based PCM audio player for Windows in C.

But even though it is basic, I still want it to perform at low latency, so I decided to use ASIO4ALL, like many DAW's allow you to do in order to achieve low latency audio playback. I've got the ASIO4ALL DLL file.

My question is : once I've loaded my wave file's raw pcm data in memory and I have a pointer to the corresponding byte array (this part of the code is already done), how do I start to "feed" the driver with the samples so that it transmits them to the sound hardware ? Is there some kind of entry point function in the dll ? I found no documentation about including/using the dll in a code project.

Comment: With other libraries like Jack, you register a callback. The dll calls the callback based on the clock from the audio card. The callback supplies the requested audio samples.

Answer (score 0):

You want Steinberg's ASIO SDK, which you can download from here:

https://new.steinberg.net/de/developers

Documentation is included in the download.